# How to multiple image add react.js

Tags: reactjs

I have all the pictures in a folder inside the react.js component like a hundred pictures. I don't want to show those pictures down or side by side. I want the pictures to come from the same place one by one

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell what your question is, but if you're wanting to have a slideshow of those 100 pictures you can use a package such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slideshow-image